# append vs appendTo when adding more products

Tags: jquery, append, appendto

This code below is executed after an ajax-call is performed (that is loaded when user scrolls down in the browser). It works correctly when using `append()`, but not using appendTo. **Why?** The reason I want to use appendTo is that I want to use a `fadeIn()` effect for new products that is loaded into the div.

**This works:**

```
nextProducts.done(function(data) {                  
    $('.products-display').append(data);

    //Using setTimeout as technique because settimeout will always
    //put the function at bottom of the call stack (so above data
    //has been appended now)
    setTimeout(function() { 
        product_offset = parseInt($('.outfit-item.product').length);                               
        $('.products-display').attr('data-currentoffset', product_offset);                            
    }, 1);      
});
```

**but NOT this (no products are added, nothing happens and no errors in console.log are given)**

```
nextProducts.done(function(data) {                  
    $( data ).appendTo( ".products-display" );
    //Using setTimeout as technique because settimeout will always
    //put the function at bottom of the call stack (so above data
    //has been appended now)
    setTimeout(function() { 
        product_offset = parseInt($('.outfit-item.product').length);                               
        $('.products-display').attr('data-currentoffset', product_offset);                            
    }, 1);      
});
```

The data-value is a json. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: what is value of data

Comment: data is a json with products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There **is** an error when you try to do `$(array).appendTo('.foo')`.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined
```

You can get around this by doing:

```
$(array.join('')).appendTo('.foo');
```

Answer (score 1):

`$( data ).appendTo` is the problem.

From the documentation: "With .appendTo(), on the other hand, the content precedes the method, either as a selector expression or as markup created on the fly, and it is inserted into the target container."

In other words, *data* has to be an html element or html markup which will be inserted into another element.